# How to disable or configure clipping when rendering to texture using FBO in OpenGL?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I have a question about the way the FBO clips the visible scene.
All this happens in iPhone's OpenGL ES.

I'm rendering in 2D and using render-to-texture with FBO.

I find that when any part of the scene passes any side of the rectangle of screen size (480*320) that it appears clipped from the FBO generated texture.

Why does it do that? How do I disable or configure it?

**I've tried** disabling scissor test by

`lDisable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);`

**I've tried** to set up needed section by

```
`glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
glScissor(0, 0, 100, 100);`
```

**I've tried** to adjust Viewport by

`glViewport(0,0, 512,512);`

it doesn't work as needed.  Instead of extending the render area to needed 512*512 it looks like it still clips the area to 480*320 and stretches it afterwards to 512*512

**All these didn't bring needed result.**

In my code:
I create the texture

```
GLuint textureID;   
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);

glGenTextures(1, &textureID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR); 
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 512, 512, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, nil);`
```

Create FBO and attach texture to it

```
GLuint textureFrameBuffer;
GLint prevFBO;
glGetIntegerv(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING_OES, &prevFBO);

// create framebuffer
glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &textureFrameBuffer);
glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, textureFrameBuffer);

// attach renderbuffer
glFramebufferTexture2DOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID, 0);

if(glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES)
    NSLog(@"ERROR - WHILE CREATING FBO");

// unbind frame buffer
glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, prevFBO);
```

And then, when I draw some stuff to FBO and render the square with this texture,

```
static const float textCoords[] = 
{
    0, 1,
    1, 1,
    0, 0,
    1, 0,
};

static const float quadVerts[] = 
{
    0, 320,
    320, 320,
    0, 0,
    320, 0,
};
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);    
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);    
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, quadVerts);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, textCoords);      
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

To my opinion I should see the square filled with all the stuff I had drawn to my FBO. Whereas, I only see a part of it – clipped rectangle of size 480x320 at lower left corner.
**So, the question is steel actual**

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your viewport doing:

```
glViewport(0,0,textureWidth,textureHeight);
```

*EDIT*:
And don't forget to switch it back to its normal value after rendering onto your FBO.

```
/// save viewport
GLint vp[4];
glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, vp);

/// restore viewport
glViewport(vp[0], vp[1], vp[2], vp[3]);
```

Comment: **The problem remains unsolved**. Thanks for the quick response despite it doesn't work as needed. Adjusting viewport gave not the effect I was looking for. Instead of extending the render area to needed 512*512 glViewport(0,0,512,512), it looks like it still clips the area to 480*320 and **stretches it** afterwards to 512*512. If anybody has the solution, please tell me.

Comment: @Marmot - In your `glTexImage2D()` and `glRenderbufferStorage()` for the offscreen FBO, did you set the width and height to be 512 x 512?

Comment: @Brad Larson – actually I don’t use renderbuffer object. I draw to texture bound to my FBO instead.

Yes, I create texture with dimensions 512x512, but I haven’t succeeded in rendering any single pixel to the area outside of 480x320 rectangle. Actually there is the case when I drew to this area. It was with viewport extended to 512x512, although in this case it just stretches the clipped section to 512x512.

Comment: @Marmot - Try using a renderbuffer object, because I think I needed to do so in order to get offscreen rendering for [this project](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/ColorTracking.zip) to work for my arbitrary non-screen-size scene.  I do all my setup there in the `-createFramebuffers` method on ColorTrackingGLView.